# Storing button state with shared preference works but name of button changes when I leave the app

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sharedpreferences

I am storing the state of my button in a shared preference and it seems to work. I am using the button to turn on a service. if I turn the service on and leave the app i can press the button again to turn it off which is good. the only thing is when I turn the service on the text in the button should change to "stop service" and it does but when i exit the app it changes back to "start service" yet the state is saved. here is where I am implementing this

```
  SharedPreferences prefs =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE);
  final String check_state = prefs.getString( "state", "default");
  holder.startsCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(check_state.equals("false")){
                            holder.startsCar.setText("Stop Car");
                            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this.getActivity(), MQTTService.class);
                            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(Home.this.getActivity(), i);
                            for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getItemCount(); j++) {
                                if (adapter1.getItem(j).isSelected(true)) {
                                     name = ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.make)).getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Inserted....." + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "true");
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            //Toast.makeText(Home.this.getContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            holder.startsCar.setText("Start Car");
                            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this.getActivity(), MQTTService.class);
                            getActivity().stopService(i);
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this.getContext(), "Service Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "false");
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Any reason on why this is happening?

Comment: You are storing the state of the button on clicking that's totally fine but what you are missing is you need to set the text again based on the sharedprefs value which you are currently missing

Comment: thanks for the reply. I haven't used shared preferences for that long. How do I implement that based on the prefs value?

Comment: I have written answer check that and let me know if it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code :

```
SharedPreferences prefs =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE);
  final String check_state = prefs.getString( "state", "default");

   if(!check_state.equals("false") {
        holder.startsCar.setText("Stop Car"); 
   }else { 
        holder.startsCar.setText("Start Car"); 
   }

  holder.startsCar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(check_state.equals("false")){
                            holder.startsCar.setText("Stop Car");
                            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this.getActivity(), MQTTService.class);
                            ContextCompat.startForegroundService(Home.this.getActivity(), i);
                            for (int j = 0; j < adapter.getItemCount(); j++) {
                                if (adapter1.getItem(j).isSelected(true)) {
                                     name = ((TextView) holder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.make)).getText().toString();
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data Inserted....." + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "true");
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                            //Toast.makeText(Home.this.getContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            holder.startsCar.setText("Start Car");
                            Intent i = new Intent(Home.this.getActivity(), MQTTService.class);
                            getActivity().stopService(i);
                            Toast.makeText(Home.this.getContext(), "Service Stoped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  Home.this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("check", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString("state", "false");
                            editor.apply();
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Notice I am setting the state of the startsCar text by using prefs in beginning

Comment: yeah that works thanks so much. One more question if you have time. see where i am looping through the adapter and storing the value of the textview in name . will that be saved in the shared preference?

Comment: you can store anything with a key name in shared prefs. That won't cause any problems if you are storing large amount of data it would be better to store in MySQL database ...check some tutorials on that...